# Delete rows that have duplicate column value in CSV file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a CSV file that contains duplicate data in columns, for example :

```
Field1;Field2;Field3;Field4;Field5
alpha;15;16;delta;delta
alpha;15;15;delta;kappa
alpha;15;15;delta;delta
alpha;15;16;delta;kappa
```

I want to delete rows that have the same value in `Field2;Field3` or `Field4;Field5` or both.

Expected output :

```
Field1;Field2;Field3;Field4;Field5
alpha;15;16;delta;kappa
```

Comment: See [ask].......

Comment: please update the question with the code (`awk`?) you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code

Comment: Something like `awk -F ';' '$2 != $3 && $4 != $5{print}' file`

Comment: @AndreWildberg: It is useful to wait with the answer until the questioner has shown what he has done to answer the question himself.

Comment: @Cyrus Agreed in general, but since this really wasn't rocket science to begin with maybe it inspires to dive into `awk` in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting `awk` script:

```
awk -F';' '$2==$3||$4==$5{next}1' input.csv
```

This will print `input.csv` excluding the required lines.

```
awk -i inplace -F';' '$2==$3||$4==$5{next}1' input.csv
```

This will update`input.csv` excluding the required lines.